# Is it possible to host a vscode webview in react outside the vscode extension project?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I created a vs code extension with a webview with react and vite, following the samples, and it's working fine.

I was wondering if it's possible to separate the webview part in a classic react project and host the site it in a service like vercel, etc and make the vs code extension communicate with the site ?

The main problem would be how pass the message between vs code and the site ?

The reason is that it's more easy to work on your website in a separate repo, deploy it and then just link it to your vscode extension

I tried to use Iframe but it seems that some code need to be injected in the site to  allow vs code and the site to communication with messaging

Comment: You can develop a web page with React for standalone hosting and embed that via an iframe into a webview if you want it in VS Code.

Comment: @MikeLischke they're asking how to do the comms between the extension and the embedded site. Your comment is useless(?)

Comment: @starball Isn't that obvious once you embedded the iframe (postMessage etc.)? The difficult part here is the nested iframe.

Comment: well, if you know for a fact that there aren't any other hitches, then find a canonical and dup vote.